# Split dictionary into two dictionaries based on key value and store into separate dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

Hi I am not familiar with Python at all and I need help manipulating a dictionary. There are questions that have a similar titles to mine but they're aren't solid solutions that solve my problem. Please consider my question I really would appreciate the help.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but this was the only way that I could think about approaching the problem. I have read in a csv file into a dictionary. Then I printed the values of that dictionary into the command prompt. I liked how it separated each row when I printed it. How can I extract only the rows from the dictionary that match the key row values that I have randomly generated in a list? The last two comments at the bottom of this post sum up where I'm stuck.

Here's the output from the program:

[image]

```
#1. read in text file using inputFileName
#should take in python argument link python decisionTree.py [trainingSetSize] 

import sys, csv, random
print "you entered these arguments", sys.argv
inputFileName = sys.argv[1]

#2. Set the trainingSetSize to desired input number
trainingSetSize = int(sys.argv[2])


#create a list variable to store the training set row key values
trainingSetList = []

text_file = open(inputFileName, "r")
numberOfRows = len(text_file.readlines()) - 1
print numberOfRows
text_file.close()

trainingSetListHoldsKeys = random.sample(range(numberOfRows), trainingSetSize)
print str(trainingSetListHoldsKeys).strip('[]')

with open(inputFileName as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     print reader

     for row in reader:
          print(row['GoodGrades'], row['GoodLetters'], row['GoodSAT'], row['IsRich'], row['HasScholarship'], row['ParentAlum'], row['SchoolActivities'], row['CLASS'], row['R'])

# Extract the rows with the desired keys from trainingSetListHoldsKeys into the training set 
# The remaining rows need to be stored in separate dictionary for the testing set
```

Comment: for the first task : *"# Extract the rows with the desired keys from trainingSetListHoldsKeys into the training set"*, does this mean extract the rows by the row numbers in the trainingSetListHoldsKeys list? if so, you could do something with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like: `for rownum, row in enumerate(reader):
        if rownum in trainingSetListHoldsKeys: print(row['GoodGrades'],...`

Comment: Yes it does. I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged some of the code and created two separate dictionaries.

```
f = open(inputFileName)

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

count = 0
trainingSet = {count: ''}
testingSet = {count: ''}
for row in csv_f:
    if count in trainingSetListHoldsKeys:
        print row
        trainingSet[count] = row
    else:
        testingSet[count] = row

    count = count + 1

print trainingSet

print '---------\n\n\n---------'

print testingSet

print '---------'
```